# Difference between all and all of the before nouns

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

Is there a difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Are they both correct?

-All big stores in my town are expensive.

-All of the big stores in my town are expensive.

My book says use "all + noun" when talking about something in general.

And "all of the + noun" when talking about something specific.

So, it should be "all of the big stores in my town" because "in my town" makes the stores specific, not general.

So, is "all big stores in my town are expensive" wrong or ungrammatical?

Comment: both versions are fine and idiomatic. The first one kind of expresses a "general rule" that is fairly absolute, while the second is just a statement of how things happen to be, but the difference is subtle and doesn't usually matter (and I'm not sure if it would be present in other English dialects at all).

Comment: Your books sounds like it has the right idea. It's not about grammar. It's about meaning.